# How to create a MySQL server with a domain as hostname?

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a MySQL cluster and I want to use port 3306 for all of the MySQL instances and the only way I can think of to do that on one ip is to create a domain as hostname, but I can't figure out how o can add a domain as hostname.

Hope you can help.

Thanks

EDIT::

**Expected result:**

Able to connect to 2 MySQL Instances on a single network with one IP:

**Network A:** (ip: 8.8.8.8)

**Instance 1:** db1.example.com **PORT** 3306

**Intance 2:** db2.example.com **PORT** 3306

---

**Network B:**  (ip: 8.8.8.9)

**Instance 3:** db3.example.com **PORT** 3306

**Intance 4:** db4.example.com **PORT** 3306

Comment: If you have a domain you can assign hostnames for any addresses you like. Normally each server in the cluster is assigned a specific name such as `cdb1.mydomain.com`, `cdb2.mydomain.com` and so on. If they all have the same name it's hard to administer them directly.

Comment: I do not try to add all of the servers to one domain, I that one MySQL instance listens to db1.example.com

Comment: Then it's not clear from your question what your goal is here, so can you elaborate on the desired outcome?

Comment: Added edit: Expected result, hope that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web browsers present the `Host` header to web servers. A server, when it sees an incoming http or https request, uses that header to route the request to one of multiple web sites it's hosting.

For example, you can have the hostnames  www.example.com and www.example.org both resolve to the IP address 10.254.253.252.  Then when a browser makes a request to `http://www.example.org` , it will arrive at the server with the header `Host: www.example.org`.

**But**. the MySQL protocol doesn't have the equivalent of the `Host` header. Therefore, you can't do what you hope to do.

Comment: With non-virtualhost services you need to differentiate by port.